# How to parse nested JSON data in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, parsing

I have some nested data in JSON from an API. I want to retrieve each of the JSON elements into separate arrays for each element type (arrays for price, size, brand, etc.).

Here is my code:

```
# Convert JSON data to a hash
json_parsed = JSON.parse(api_data)

# If server status returned is 200, proceed
if json_parsed["statusCode"] = "200"
  styleID[0] = json_parsed["styleID"]
  puts styleID[0]
end
```

This returns a blank line. There are multiple styleIds in a nested manner for each product returned from the API. I tried uses Ruby#Hash using pp, but I have been unsuccessful in reading through the nest to retrieve each of the product details.

My logic is to use a matrix of multiple arrays:

```
array_of_prod_id = ["prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4"]

array_of_brand = ["brand1", "brand2", "brand3", "brand4"] 

array_of_sizes = ["size1", "size2", "size3", "size4"] 

and so on... for other product details.
```

prod1 corresponds to brand1 which corresponds to other details of the product (same index numbers). I retrieve them by using the same index numbers on all arrays.

Is there a better approach to dealing with this kind of data in Rails?

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 on Rails 4.0.

Comment: It would be better if you'd provide an input json string.

Comment: What does your `api_data` look like?

Comment: I was able to figure the hashes out. The outside wrapper was called "results" so I accessed the values I wanted through json_parsed["results"][index]["productID"].